# Why css "text-decoration" inheritance does not work for "inline-block"?

Tags: html, css

I wonder - why "text 2" is not underlined?

```html
<div style="text-decoration: underline;">
  <div>text 1</div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <div>text 2</div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline;">
    <div>text 3</div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: block;">
    <div>text 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's by spec, text decoration does not apply **exactly** in your case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the following sentences on the CSS specification:

> Underlines, overlines, and line-throughs are applied only to text (including white space, letter spacing, and word spacing): margins, borders, and padding are skipped. User agents must not render these text decorations on content that is not text. For example, **images and inline blocks must not be underlined**.
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#lining-striking-props

Comment: Interesting. Then "flex" should also have been excluded too, right? But I just tried and they seem to inherit text-decoration.